# altering font size and style in PickerView sections

Tags: ios, uipickerview

My font picker is now working fine,

all that is missing is 2 extra sections in the PickerView for font size and style (bold, italic and underlined).

I don't know how to approach changing these values.

This is my picker's code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     fontNames = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
            [fontNames addObject:fontName];
        }
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return fontNames.count;



}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return [fontNames objectAtIndex:row];

}



- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component
           reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80, 32);
    pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    pickerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    pickerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fontNames objectAtIndex:row]];
    pickerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[fontNames objectAtIndex:row] size:15];




    return pickerLabel;

}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    _fontLabel.text = [fontNames objectAtIndex:row];
    _fontLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[fontNames objectAtIndex:row] size:15];
}

@end
```

Comment: How about populate the view with all 260 recognized fonts?

Comment: That is what i am trying to do, the question is how

Comment: Did you read this? What is the question? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html

Comment: Question is too broad. Show what things you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: will edit again. please stop rep-bashing

Comment: can you please put it off hold and stop randomly down voting? thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You get the fonts using this loop:

```
NSMutableArray *fontNames = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        [fontNames addObject:fontName];
    }
}
```

How you present the picker depends on your UI layout. You might use an UITableView in an UIPopoverController (just google it, you'll find TONS of quite good tutorials) or an UIPickerView.

Comment: added your loop into my code, tried using the array as data source. returned new exceptions. see edited code.

Comment: You absolutely misunderstood, how UIKit works. You can't set a mutableArray as the dataSource of the pickerView. The pickerView must be of type `(id<UIPickerViewDataSource>)`. You can adopt the UIPickerViewDelegate and -dataSource in your header, implement it and set the delegate to `self`. The best would be watching a tutorial on UIPickerView OR UITableView on youtube (they work similar).

Comment: can you add an example of that to your answer?

Comment: Well then. Have you got more problems? Please don't edit your question so often. It might get off-topic then. If you face another issue please ask a new question

Comment: i think there is a logical error in my code that makes me get the wrong fonts

Comment: You don't use the font names, but the family names. Use the code I gave you and it will work.

Comment: my last problem is edited in

Comment: You should have asked a new question, because my answer is now completely off-topic after the topic is all new. Please read FAQ and help sections! Your Question is on hold now and I can't answer anymore.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33568/discussion-between-julian-and-exothug)